# How to switch to ESS mode manually?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I sometimes use emacs with the "It's all text" firefox extension to write in textareas, and
sometimes I need to insert R code into the file, which is usually named something like
"stackoverflow.com.231x234.txt", which is of course triggers the text mode. How can I switch
to ESS mode manually in this case? I know I can do "M-x python-mode" for python,
but I don't what the equivalent is for ESS.

Answer (score 2):

`M-x R-mode` should do the trick.